# ASP.NET 5 - passing parameter to AuthorizationHandler<T>

Tags: asp.net

I am attempting to create a custom `AuthorizationHandler<T>` in `ASP.NET 5`, but need the handler to have access to a parameter (or the url to extract the parameter)

I'm not finding any way to do this, though;

```
public class Owner : AuthorizationHandler<Owner>, IAuthorizationRequirement {
    protected override void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, Owner requirement) {
        // no access to an HttpContext or any sort of parameters
    }
}
```

The parameter will be part of the URL on the `IActionResult` method in the controller where the attribute is attached.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the docs (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html#accessing-request-context-in-handlers) you can use `context.Resource as Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Filter.AuthorizationContext` to access everything MVC knows about the current request.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed!